# Java-Oracle UniversalConnectionPool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, database-performance

I am working on a financial application where lots of agents hit the DB (Using UI) very frequently. I am using Oracle UniversalConnectionPool for DB Connection. But soon it creates lots of inactive sessions with DB. I don't have issues with inactive sessions because it puts them in the pool but problem is that after reaching the max limit it give error that

> Exception occurred while getting connection:
> oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: All connections in the
> Universal Connection Pool are in use

Here is the code please have a look and help

```
private static PoolDataSource  pds = null;
static UniversalConnectionPoolManager mgr = null;
try{
    pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
    pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
        pds.setConnectionPoolName("JDBC_UCP");
        
        pds.setInitialPoolSize(2);
        pds.setMinPoolSize(2);
        pds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        
        pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.4.5:1521:CDIM");
        pds.setUser("baseline");
        pds.setPassword("baseline");
        
        mgr = UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManager();
        mgr.createConnectionPool((UniversalConnectionPoolAdapter)pds);
        mgr.startConnectionPool("JDBC_UCP");
    }catch(Exception e){
        LogManager.error(DBConnection.class, "getConnection : " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

get Connection like this

```
pds.getConnection();
```

Close Connection like this

```
con.close();
con = null;
```

Comment: Please check if connection is being closed in case of database call exception.

Comment: Not sure, how you are closing your connections. But, if you are using plain JDBC make sure you do this within finally block. Alternatively, if you use any ORM implementation or Spring DAO, they do it for you.

Comment: This have been taken care properly that connections are closed in finally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you're closing the connections (as best you can) you should also look into some of the connection managing features of UCP (e.g. abandonedConnectionTimeout and connection harvesting).  There is a good article that discusses [UCP optimization](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e12265/optimize.htm).